# Qt Library Linking

Tags: c++, qt, templates, dll, dynamic-linking

I am currently trying to get my head around library linking with Qt in order to split up some existing code into logically structured modular parts that can be called by different applications.

I keep getting a problem where no obj files are being created... so I have created a smaller sample project and replicated my problem below.

It seems, to me, the problem lies in the library ...so I will start there.

If I have code like this, the obj file is created (and can therefore be linked to by my test application):

mylib.h

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

#include "mylib_global.h"

class MYLIB_EXPORT MyLib
{
public:
    MyLib();
    ~MyLib();

private:

};

#endif // MYLIB_H
```

mylib.cpp

```
#include "mylib.h"

MyLib::MyLib()
{

}

MyLib::~MyLib()
{

}
```

But if I remove the cpp file and just have the header file with function bodys included (as is the structure of my actual codes library as the code consists ONLY of templates), nothing is created:

mylib.h

```
// .......
public:
    MyLib(){}
    ~MyLib(){}
// .......
```

How can I get Qt to build my code please?

Comment: How your Qt project for the library looks like? Besides, if you have code with templates, compiler probably does not generate code for it, as you do not instantiate any object of templated class.

Comment: If I clean the whole solution (vs2013) and build only the library, the first example above creates an obj file. Is this not creating an obj file that the application can link against. I get an error saying "error LNK1104: cannot open file xxx\mylib.lib" if I make the function bodies part of the class itself and try and build everything.

Answer (score 0):

If your library is just a header file, you don't need to compile it, include your headers in your other projects, and they will be compiled into it.

Comment: I don't undrstand what you want to do exactly, but if you library is just a header (.h), you only need to include it in your Qt application (using  `#include`)

Comment: I have about 200 header files that are shared between several applications. I intend to only have a single copy of the code (hence the library) that can be used by all the applications. I hoped to have multiple library projects that would act as "containers" (one for each namespace) that could be referenced from each of my projects.

Comment: then, the only way i can think of to solve this problem is to use a one header file that include the other headers, and in your application just include that one file.
This technique is used by Qt, for example, if you  include <QtGui>, it  will include all the gui headers in Qt

Comment: Well, I actually do that. I have multiple dlls (one for each namespace) and then an all encompassing dll that contains nothing but a header file pointing to each namespace (for the odd project that might be relevent to the whole of the codebase)... but I don't see how this solves my problem? That header file contains nothing but a series of #include... and therefore doesn't have a cpp file to make it compile... bringing me back to the start of the problem, no?

Comment: either you compile those files or not, you will need to include them into your projects, i mean your library might be just headers or headers+dll. the only way for headers+dll approach is to move the implementation from headers to .cpp files

Comment: So, if I wanted to give the dll's to someone else to implement (but didnt want them to have anything but the definitions) by using templated classes throughout, they would have to have access to ALL my code???!